# How to change GENYMOTION screen orientation?

Tags: android, orientation, emulation, landscape, genymotion

Is it possible to change the orientation of the genymotion emulator?
Is there a shotcut or setting to change this?

I've tried to google it but have not find it.
Any suggestion would be appreciated,thank you.

Comment: there is a button in the sidebar, one which looks like vibrate.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Two ways :

- Button in the sidebar
- CTRL + F11

Edit : 
And if it does not work, it's surely because the application in foreground is orientation locked.

Comment: It seems that this doesn't work when you are in the home screen but works when you open an app.

Comment: True - on Mac it's Cmd+F11. However, there seems to be a bug where emulator window orientation is not in sync with android's orientation. Not sure how to reach this state, but I've managed to 'fix' it by restarting the emulator.

Comment: Worked on windows  10.

Answer (score 6):

When device rotates after pressing vibration-like icon, this icon disappears preventing the device from rotating back from landscape to portrait. My solution for this is:

1. Open genymotion shell and
2. type  `rotation setangle 180` ([user guide](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/developers/user-guide) documentation)

This will return device again to landscape. I just tried it.

Comment: There is actually a menu button at the bottom of the list of buttons that contains the "Rotate Screen" button.

Answer (score 5):

It seems on Mac it is in the latest version **CMD + F11** and not **CTRL + F11**, although it is documented to be the last one.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you can just go to the :

Settings >> Display

And uncheck the "auto-rotate" option.It will turn back it's initial rotation.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

In landscape mode, the Rotate screen button does not appear (for some devices at least) and the CMD + F11 (for mac) did not work for me. I solved this with the following steps:

1. from landscape, click the Home button (go back to the home screen)
2. on home screen, press CMD + F11 (for mac)
3. relaunch the app from the genymotion emulator, this should restore the portrait mode.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 3):

Just do the following,

1. navigate to Settings -> Configuration -> Custom
2. change from ex: 800x1280 to 1280x800
3. reset

hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me.

In genymotion start screen,
Right click on the device.
Select settings
And inside it change height and width values.