# Android emulator upside down

Tags: android, android-emulator, titanium-mobile

I am using Titanium to build an app. I created an android emulator using a standard device definition Nexus 4 (4.7", 768X1280: xhdpi, Android 4.1.2 - APU Level 16 , ARM (armebi-v7a) when I run it , the outside orientation appears correct but the screen itself is upside down. See image:

! [upside down emulator] (http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=c0d737c)

I have deleted the emulator and re-created it a couple of times. I chose this one as it appears to have the highest screen density and the smallest screen physical size. Is there a way to fix this? when my app runs, it does appear correctly, but using the emulator is weird. Loke for opening the app drawer, you don't click on the icon where it is displayed, but you click where it should be.

Comment: Ctrl + F12 may rotate the screen

Comment: This only happens on one of 3 machines for me. It is a GPU issue as noted below. Rotating the screen does not fix it because it then appears inside out. IOW, a mirror image, as if you were inside the phone looking out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unchecking the "Use Host GPU" corrects the situation. I do not know why, but it does.

Comment: This helped also in Linux Android Studio and some weird bug where only half the emulator screen was upside down.

Answer (score 5):

Try  **left Ctrl + F12**. to rotate emulator.

also [refer](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html)

Comment: Cmd F11 for mac.. also does not fix it from being upside down.
See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20538711/how-to-change-genymotion-screen-orientation

Answer (score 1):

The fix to this for me was very simple. I entered the resolution as height x width and it was upside down. So I entered width x height and it became OK.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your XML and set proper background to the parent view.